# Facebook Page Tab - "LIKE" button not reloading page

Tags: facebook

I've set up a simple app to run in a page tab.  After authorizing the use of the app, just for basic info, it checks if the user likes the page.  If they don't it asks for you to like the page before proceeding - but if you click the LIKE button at that point it's not refreshing the page so I don't see the change in my app.  The user is left hanging and has to click the page tab again to proceed, at which point it lets you in.  If you like the page before starting, everything works fine and the LIKE button refreshes the page as normal.

Is there a reason for this?  Or am I missing a trick - should I add my own LIKE button or something?

Help appreciated as I'm really new to facebook apps.

EDIT - I'm using Asp.Net C# if that makes a difference.  I found it very hard to find any good documentation so I've pieced this together as best I can, so excuse the messiness.  Here's the HTML page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '9999999999',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true // parse XFBML
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1300 });
    }
    // Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
    function sizeChangeCallback() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1300 });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:520px;margin:0; padding:0; border:0;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="fb-root">
    <div id="intro" runat="server" style="width:520px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        Enter our competition<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="authorise" runat="server" Text="authorise" OnClick="Authorise_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="voting" runat="server" visible="false" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:520px;padding:0px">
        <div id="notliked" runat="server" visible="false">
            You must LIKE our page before you can enter the competition
        </div>
        <div id="questions" runat="server" visible="false">
            <div id="week1" runat="server" visible="false">
                Q1 Q2 Q3    
            </div>
            <div id="week2" runat="server" visible="false">
                Q4 Q5 Q6
            </div>
            <div id="entereddiv" runat="server" visible="false">
                You have already entered this week's competition.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="terms" runat="server" style="color:Black;font-size:11px;width:450px;">

    </div>  
</div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '9999999999', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: false });

        // If like button pressed, refresh page
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) { top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/MY_PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=app_9999999999'; });

    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It normally refreshes the page. Try it somewhere else, https://www.facebook.com/cocacola

Comment: It does refresh, but not immediately after authorising the app.  If I do as explained above, restart the app, click unlike and then use the LIKE button it works, just not in the place I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've actually sorted this out - I didn't realise I could get the isLiked property without having the user authorise the app.  Now I've switched it around so I check signedrequest first and get them to like the page before asking for authorisation.  This gets me around the problem.

I still think it's a bug with Facebook that you can't do that but for this project this solution will do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen Facebook JS API actions and do a callback to refresh page.

Try to add this code block at the end of your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({appId: '<appID>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: false });

        // If like button pressed, refresh page
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { top.location = '<Page Address>';  } );

    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work, I've edited to add the html code, including yours as it stands now.  IDs obviously changed

Comment: can you give your fan page and application tab link?

Comment: Ok, I've made the test area public for a while: http://www.facebook.com/pages/IWL-Developers/272359529459745?sk=app_272190626163104

Comment: Still no joy - I've tried it a few different ways and it's still not working.  Could it be the asp.net postback affecting it or something?  gonna have to hide the dev area again in a while so if you're still looking please let me know

Comment: I've tried adding an alert in there instead of the redirect but that doesn't fire either...

Comment: aha! i misunderstood stg. I guessed you put your own like button and didn't refresh the page, the code above for your own like button.

Comment: if you are trying to get user liked or not, you can get by signed_request of page. in php , here it is the sample: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ , isLiked parameter does not need your app permission's also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5984/discussion-between-tolga-arican-and-dave)